# Composer doesn't work behind proxy

Tags: php, proxy, composer-php, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to download Laravel on Ubuntu 16.04, but I'm having troubles trying to get Composer to work on our network. I believe that the issue is either related to our proxy server or a firewall, both of which (unfortunate) are managed by our parent organisation.

I'm trying to run this command:

```
sudo composer global require "laravel/installer"
```

Which gives me this error:

```
Changed current directory to /home/administrator/.composer

[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Cannot assign requested address

require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--no-plugins] [--no-progress] [--no-update] [--update-no-dev] [--update-with-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--] [<packages>]...
```

When I run *composer diag*, I get the following output:

```
Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK
Checking http connectivity to packagist: FAIL
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "http://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Cannot assign requested address
Checking https connectivity to packagist: FAIL
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Cannot assign requested address
Checking github.com rate limit: FAIL
[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "https://api.github.com/rate_limit" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Connection refused
Checking disk free space: OK
```

Now, I've run this command to set the proxy:

```
export HTTP_PROXY="http://proxy.<url>:8080"
```

I've also modified */etc/profile* to add in the following information:

```
export HTTP_PROXY_REQUEST_FULLURI=0 # or false
export HTTPS_PROXY_REQUEST_FULLURI=0 #
```

And I've disabled ipv6 (in */etc/sysctl.conf*), as I noticed that has caused issues in the past:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

Which works (as apt-get uses it), but I can't seem to get curl to work at all. Is there another variable that I should be setting?

Answer (score 0):

You need to establish environment vars 
http_proxy = http://username:password@ip:port
and 
https_proxy = http://username:password@ip:port
in your SO